# Extract multiple substrings from same string efficiently

Tags: scala

I have a large dataset of URL strings containing key-value pairs, and I want to capture a list of values from that string.  One example of a string is below:

```
"GET /no_cache/bi_page?Log=1&pg_inst=600474500174606089&pg=mdot_fyc_pnt&platform=mdot&ver=10.c110&pid=157876860906745096&rid=157876731027276387&srch_id=-2&row=7&seq=1&tot=1&tsp=1&test_name=m_control&logDomain=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xyz.com&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.xyz.com%2F&z=44134 HTTP/1.1"
```

So if my list of values to return come from keys: "pg","test_name","some_other_key" ... I'd want the function to return ("mdot_fyc","m_control","NA") for this row.

I could just write three separate regex lines to capture each value.  But some of these strings are long and I could have dozens of these values to extract instead of just three.

What's the most efficient way to extract multiple values from the same string?

Comment: do you need to use regex?  Can you use string manipulation methods like `split`?

Comment: When you say "large dataset" what do you mean? Hundreds? Thousands? Millions? Have you tried something already and found it too inefficient? You may not need to care how efficient it is depending on your expected data set. It's probably not efficient, but if you just want a set of keys I'd parse the url and generate a map of key/value pairs, extracting the pairs you're interested in.

Comment: By large I mean millions of rows.  I have tried using "split" but it takes like 3x time to run on my sample.

Comment: I like to use `NET-A-PORTER` for URL parsing, but I've never tried it on millions of URLs: https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/scala-uri

Comment: You can find Aho–Corasick algorithm useful in this case. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm. You can find Java implementations from that page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple 1-pass solution. Let me know if it's fast enough.

I'm no expert in URLs, so it might need tuning. Basically it assumes that there are no unescaped spaces, '?', '&' or '=' characters.

It can be further smoothed with low-level opti.

```
def extractParams(params: List[String], from: String): Map[String, String] = {
  val a = from.toCharArray
  val len = a.length

  import scala.annotation.tailrec
  @tailrec
  def extract(p: Set[String], start: Int, results: Map[String, String]): Map[String, String] = {
    var paramStart = start
    var nextEquals = -1
    var nextAmpersand = -1

    if (start == 0) {  // find start of params
      var i = 0
      while (i < len && a(i) != '?') {
        i += 1
      }
      if (i == len) return results
      paramStart = i
    }

    { // find equals
      var i = paramStart
      while (i < len && a(i) != '=') {
        i += 1
      }
      if (i == len) return results
      nextEquals = i
    }

    { // find nextAmpersand or end
      var i = nextEquals
      while (i < len && !(a(i) == '&' || a(i) == ' ')) {
        i += 1
      }
      nextAmpersand = i
    }
    val paramNameArr = new Array[Char](nextEquals - paramStart - 1)
    System.arraycopy(a, paramStart + 1, paramNameArr, 0, nextEquals - paramStart - 1)
    val paramName = new String(paramNameArr)
    var newResults = results
    var newP = p
    if (p.contains(paramName)) { // find param value
      val paramValueArr = new Array[Char](nextAmpersand - nextEquals - 1)
      System.arraycopy(a, nextEquals + 1, paramValueArr, 0, nextAmpersand - nextEquals - 1)
      val paramValue = new String(paramValueArr)
      newResults = newResults + (paramName -> paramValue)
      newP = p - (paramName)
    }
    if (nextAmpersand == len || a(nextAmpersand) == ' ') { // check for end
      return newResults
    } else {
      return extract(newP, nextAmpersand, newResults)
    }
  }
  extract(params.toSet, "GET ".length, Map.empty)
}
```